# How to add JavaBeans to an ArrayList in the session?

Tags: jsp, arraylist, javabeans

This is an exercise from our Professor. I am kinda stuck. First he wants us to Store a company name and price in a JavaBean we will create – one price and company per instance. This means we require three bean instances.

Please see, he wants us to hard-code in three companies and prices using the above method.

Then, He wants us to Add the JavaBeans to an ArrayList in the session & Forward to a JSP for display.

This is what I am upto now,

```
    <jsp:useBean id="company1" class="beans.Invoice" scope="session"></jsp:useBean>
    <jsp:useBean id="company2" class="beans.Invoice" scope="session"></jsp:useBean>
    <jsp:useBean id="company3" class="beans.Invoice" scope="session"></jsp:useBean>

    <jsp:setProperty property="companyName" name="company1" value="Telco" />
    <jsp:setProperty property="price" name="company1" value="23" />

    <jsp:setProperty property="companyName" name="company2" value="Telcos" />
    <jsp:setProperty property="price" name="company2" value="25" />

    <jsp:setProperty property="companyName" name="company3" value="Telcoi" />
    <jsp:setProperty property="price" name="company3" value="27" />
```

On the same jsp, I am doing this,

```
<%
        ArrayList<Object> disp = new ArrayList();
        disp.add(company1);
        disp.add(company2);
        disp.add(company3);

        HttpSession sess = request.getSession();
        session.setAttribute("disp", disp);

%>
```

Then on next JSP as required by him, I am doing this,

```
   <%
        ArrayList<String> list = (ArrayList<String>) request.getSession()
                .getAttribute("disp");

        for (String r : list) {
            out.println(r);
        }
    %>
```

Here is the error I get

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: beans.Invoice cannot be cast to java.lang.String
```

Where I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're storing instances of `Invoice` in the first JSP, in an `ArrayList<Object>`. But in the second JSP, you're trying to get Strings out of this list. An `Invoice` is not a `String`. It's an `Invoice`.

So the code of the second JSP should be

```
List<Invoice> list = (List<Invoice>) request.getSession().getAttribute("disp");
for (Invoice r : list) {
    out.println(r);
}
```

Note that your first JSP code could also be improved. Why use a `List<Object>` when what you want is in fact a `List<Invoice>`? Its code should be

```
List<Invoice> disp = new ArrayList<Invoice>();
disp.add(company1);
disp.add(company2);
disp.add(company3);
```

And you should also use another name than "disp" for your variable and attribute. How about something more descriptive like "invoices"?

Finally, JSPs shouldn't use scriplets at all, and shouldn't be used to store objects in the session. The first JSP only contains code, and doesn't generate any markup. It should be implemented as a servlet, and not as a JSP. And it should store invoices in a request attribute and not in the session. The session should only be used to store things that have a session lifetime (like the current user's name, preferences, or things like that).

The second JSP should use the JSP EL and the JSTL rather than useing scriptlets.

Answer (score 0):

<% ArrayList < object >  list  = ( ArrayList < object >)  request . getSession () . getAttribute ( "disp" ); for ( yourClassName  r  :  list ) { out . println ( r.companyName and others ); }     %> your con't cast your object type to string...